# Selenium, java, js "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, syntax

When I put either of the following codes into chrome's developer's tools console they work fine. However, when I put them into Selenium I get the "missing ) after argument list" error. I'm aware that this probably means that the issue is likely due to incorrect syntax, but I'm not sure how or why this is the case. *Note these attempts were done separately*.

```
//Attempt 1
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;    
        js.executeScript( "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');" +
        "evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 382, 290 , false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
        "var cb = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');"+
        "cb.dispatchEvent(evt);"+
        "setTimeout(function(){"+
        "evt.initMouseEvent('mouseup', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 382, 290 false, false, false, false, 0, null);"+ 
        "cb.dispatchEvent(evt);}, 100); };"); 

//Attempt 2 
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;   
        js.executeScript( "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');" +
        "evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 382, 290 , false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
        "var cb = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');"+
        "cb.dispatchEvent(evt);"+
        "evt.initMouseEvent('mouseup', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 382, 290 false, false, false, false, 0, null);"+ 
        "cb.dispatchEvent(evt);");
```

Comment: In both of the attempts the second `evt.initMouseEvent` line lacks a comma between `290` and `false`.

Comment: Oh wow... that's what I get for copying and pasting like a bum. Hold on let me try it.

Comment: Well, I managed to make that same mistake across every iteration I tried. So... I'm putting on my glasses now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In both of the attempts the second evt.initMouseEvent line lacks a comma between 290 and false. – Teemu 28 mins ago

There's also an extra "};" after the "100);".